# How to replace internal links with a view (similar like the Open Graph feature)?

Tags: views, theming, navigation

I would like to have the feature, that if users on my site post internal links within a text, this links are replaced by a thumbnail, node title etc. For choosing what to show instead of the link I would like to use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views).
What would be the best method to do so?

- I think, a simple replacement with [hook_node_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_submit/7) or
  something, is not a good solution: If the user edits his content, I
  want him to see only what he added himself.
- I could do it within the template, but this is not very elegant, I guess.
- What is about [hook_url_outbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7), would that be the best way?

Please give me a hint.

Comment: this sounds more like an input filter to me, eg, substituting `http://www.foo.com/bar/baz` in text with a clickable link wrapped around whatever the main image is.

Comment: users might post links to node body field or any textarea fields?

Comment: Just in the body field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to write text filter and add it to input formats your users will be using. Here you have [Basic description of filters and formats](http://drupal.org/node/213156) - for Drupal 5 and 6, but concept is still valid. They are applied on display - Drupal agrees with you that you should save just what user wrote.

You need to use [hook_filter_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!filter!filter.api.php/function/hook_filter_info/7). Read about it, and then about [rest of filter hooks family](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!filter!filter.api.php/7) and you will have an idea.

To provide proper content for filter, well, there is no definitive solution. If users will only input node id, simple node_load is enough. Every set of scenarios and every use case calls for it own methods. Views are elastic tools, I guess for pretty big part of use cases they can be the tool.

Comment: The fastest replay I ever got. Thank you, that seems to be exactly what I was looking for!